# Week to Date data filter

Tags: t-sql

**Given** the following data:

StudentAbsences([StudentID], [DateAbsent], [ReasonCode])

StudentDetails([StudentID],[GivenNames],[Surname],[YearLevel],[House])

**Problem:** I am trying to generate a report for a client what want to see the top 3+ students that have been absent during a particular period. This period can be anywhere from the last week to last month to last year. My current report is giving them:

```
Student's Name (concatenation of GivenNames and Surname)
Unexplained (Number of Unexplained Absences during that particular period)
All Year to Date (The count of ALL the different types of Absence reasons for YTD)
Year Level (The student's Year Level)
```

Trouble is they now want a "Week to Date" column as well but just for Unexplained Absences. This mean that they want to see the number of absences for each student starting from Monday of that particular week.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first take.  Get the top 3 students missing with week.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime,
        @EndDate DateTime

SELECT @StartDate=DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0), @EndDate=GetDate()

SELECT D.*
FROM StudentDetails D
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 3 StudentID
FROM StudentAbsences
WHERE DateAbsent Between @StartDate and @EndDate
GROUP BY StudentID, CONVERT (nvarchar(10),DateAbsent, 102)
ORDER BY  COUNT(CONVERT (nvarchar(10),DateAbsent, 102)) DESC) A ON A.StudentID = D.StudentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
DECLARE 
  @today  datetime,
  @monday datetime

SELECT 
  @today  = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101),
  -- modulus is necessary, because report may be run on Sunday
  @monday = DATEADD(day, -1 * ((DATEPART(weekday, @today) + 5) % 7), @today)

SELECT @today, @monday

SELECT
  SA.StudentId,
  // OtherData...,
  T.WeekToDate
FROM
  StudentAbsences SA

  INNER JOIN StudentDetails SD
  ON SA.StudentId = SD.StudentId

  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT WeekToDate = COUNT(*)
    FROM StudentAbsences
    WHERE 
      Studentid = SA.StudentId
      AND 
      DateAbsent >= @monday
      AND 
      ReasonCode = 'Unexplained' -- substitute with actual unexplained code
  ) T
```